# Handle <select> values with ajax in module class, prestashop 1.6

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing a ps module which let you classify the product attachment in categories an display them in the front product page.

I'm using a draggable list with the attachment, and when you drop them to the category it turns to an option tag, each category has a select tag where to drop the attachment.

I want to save the attachments and the category where they was dropped, so I thought make an ajax call to bring the data to my module class but I'm new with ajax and cant approach it.

this is what I've made:

the js code (inside the proper .tpl):

```
<script>
        $( ".droptrue" ).droppable({
                
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    //add <option> tag when an attachment is dropped to category's select
                    $(event.target).append('<option value="' + ui.draggable.attr('id') + '" selected>'+ui.draggable.text()+'</option>');
                    //remove the <li> which contained the attachment data
                    ui.draggable.fadeOut("slow").remove();
                    
                    var val = $('#categoryAttachmentArr').val();
                  //var tab = val.split(',');
                  //for (var i=0; i < tab.length; i++)
                  //if (tab[i] == $(this).val())
                  //     return false;
                    //create an array with the next format: 'id_category(1)'-'id_attachment(1)','id_category(2)'-'id_attachment(2)'[....]
                    //the comma will be the main character that will be splitted
                    $('#categoryAttachmentArr').val(val + ui.doppable.attr('id') + '-' + ui.draggable.attr('id') +',');
                }
        });
        
        $('#submitAddProduct').click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: baseDir + 'modules/adjuntos/classes/CategoryAttachment.php',
              data: {
                        ajax: true,
                        action: \'CategoryArray\',
                        cat_array: $('#categoryAttachmentArray').val(),
                    }
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(json) {
                console.log($('#categoryAttachmentArray').val());
              }
        });
        })
    
        $( ".ui-state-default" ).draggable({ 
                
                revert: "valid",
            
        });
</script>
```

And my class:

```
class CategoryAttachment extends Objectmodel
{
     //other functions
     public function ajaxProcessCategoryArray()
    {
        $CategoryAttachmentArr = Tools::getValue('cat_array')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I got the solution, maybe one of you guys will have this problem in the future.

My code in the .tpl:

```
$( ".ui-state-default" ).draggable();

        $( ".droptrue" ).droppable({

                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    //add <option> tag when an attachment is dropped to category's select
                    $(event.target).append('<option value="' + ui.draggable.attr('id') + '" selected>'+ui.draggable.text()+'</option>');
                    $('#selectAttachment1').append('<option value="' + ui.draggable.attr('id') + '" selected>'+ui.draggable.text()+'</option>')
                    //remove the <li> wich contained the attachment data
                    ui.draggable.fadeOut("slow").remove();

                    var val = $('#categoryAttachmentArr').val();
                    //make a serialize() type array
                    $('#categoryAttachmentArr').val(val + $(this).attr('id') + "=" + ui.draggable.attr('id') +"&");

                    var value = $('#arrayAttachments').val();
                    var tab = value.split(',');
                    for (var i=0; i < tab.length; i++)
                        if (tab[i] == ui.draggable.attr('id')){

                            return false;
                        }
                    $('#arrayAttachments').val(value+ui.draggable.attr('id')+',');

                }
        });


        $('#submitCategories').click(function(e){
            var array = $('#categoryAttachmentArr').val()
            $.ajax({
              url: '../modules/adjuntos/ajax-call.php',
              data: {
                  action: 'handlearray',
                  token:new Date().getTime(),
                  cat: array
              },
              method: 'POST',
              success:function(data){
               $('#result').html(data);
             }
        });
        });
```

the ajax call goes to my ajax-call.php file:

```
<?php
 //load ps config
 require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../config/config.inc.php');
 require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../init.php');
 require_once('adjuntos.php');
 //adjuntos.php is the name of my module main file
 if(Tools::getIsset('token') && Tools::getIsset('action'))
 {
     $mp = new Adjuntos;
     echo $mp->handleArray();
 }
```

The handleArray function in my module main file:(it make a call to my custom class)

```
public static function handleArray()
{

    $html = '';
    $array = Tools::getValue('cat');
    $arrayExplode = explode("&", $array);
    foreach($arrayExplode as $value)
    {
        $finalArr = explode("=", $value);
        if (!CategoryAttachment::postProcess($finalArr))
        {
            $html .= '<p style="color:red;>Fallo</p>"';
        }     
    }
    $html .= '<p style="color:green;>Correcto</p>"';
    return $html;
  }
```

The function in my custom class:

```
public static function postProcess($finalArr)
    {

        return Db::getInstance()->execute(
                'UPDATE ps_attachment SET id_category = '.$finalArr[0].' WHERE id_attachment = '.$finalArr[1]
               );


    }//end
```

This way is working like a charm, and make the code more scalable

Answer (score 0):

you can't connect directly to any class. you have to use the controller to do this.

Ajax send data to controller

Controller save data using class

Controller return result to browser (javascript)

Comment: thanks for answer!! so i have to create a new controller, or just need to create a new php file to handle this. Or maybe use an actual admincontroller (products controller for instance).

Can you give me an example?

Comment: you can use custom (front/admin)Controller in your module or use available Hooks on your page to handle your ajax process. The first way is recommended.